# Java : howto resolve java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, native, java-3d

when i tried to run a Java 3d PROGRAM , it gave me the following error .

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

I followed this web site to solve this error

```
http://www.filsa.net/2008/07/17/eclipse-java3d-and-javalibrarypath/
```

It says that , after adding the jar files 
Additionally, you need to put the native code, j3dcore-ogl.dll (j3dcore-ogl.so on Linux) onto the PATH.

I have got these dll files under the 
j3d-1_5_2-windows-i586\bin\j3dcore-ogl.dll folder

I added this support from Eclipse this way Java Build Path --->Add Exernal Class Folder -->and upto bin path (Exactly there at which these dll files are residing )

After doing this step also , i am getting the same exception .
This is how my Eclipse IDE build path  looks now 
[image]

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 4):

I solved the question, very easy: 
Just copy & paste & merge the j3d library's `bin/ & lib/` folders into the corresponding `bin/ & lib/` folders of both the `jre/ & jdk/` JVM folders that you use.

1. Download corresponding j3d Zip binaries at https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html. For me, a win7 64bit Java VM (aka. jdk & jre), I choose `j3d-1_5_2-windows-amd64.zip`.

   UnZip the downloaded j3d Zip binaries (`j3d-1_5_2-windows-amd64.zip`) to get the `j3d-jre.zip` file inside.

   UnZip the `j3d-jre.zip` to get the `bin/ & lib/` folders.

   Copy & paste & merge the obtained `bin/ & lib/` folders into the corresponding `bin/ & lib/` folders of my JVM folders (aka. both `jdk/ & jre/` folders).

For other JVMs, it's the same thing - copy & paste & merge the j3d zip library's `bin/ & lib/` folders into the corresponding `bin/ & lib/` folders of the JVM's `jre/ & jdk/`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try executing regsvr32 "name_of_dll-file" from the run menu? You need to reboot the machine for this to take effect.

This adds the DLL as a library that other programs can access. Adding it to the Eclipse build path is not the right thing since that will only be accessible to your JVM.

Comment: when i tried things asyou mentioned , i am getting this exception , http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hr1y5v&s=5 ( This happens with all the dll files )

Answer (score 0):

Copy .dll file to Windows/system32 folder, then press (Windows + R) to start (Run)

in the field, type `regsvr32 "dll_name"`

"dll_name" is the name of the file in bin folder of the library.

Answer (score -1):

i solved problem by copying j3dcore-ogl.dll to windows/system32 folder

Comment: Could be a good answer, could you elaborate?  Also, capitalizing the "I" helps.